# Загрузить изображение в GoogleDrive

Tags: java, android

При загрузке изображения в google drive иногда он загружается нормально памяти хватает, но иногда вываливает java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 63489036 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 21MB until OOM
в коде я декодирую его в изображение переворачиваю изображение если надо будет, и указываю content type и загружаю в Google Drive.
Ошибка выходит при декодировании изображения. Как можно это обойти, мне обязательно нужно загружать изображение не обрезанное и полное.

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap  image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mSettings.getString(Const.directory, "") + "/" + file.getName(), bmOptions);
if (Picture.getCameraPhotoOrientation(file) !=0) {
    image = Picture.rotateBitmap(image, 270);
}
OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
try {
    outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e1) {
    log(e1 + "");
}
MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle(file.getName()).build();
DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient, DriveId.decodeFromString(stringFolderId));
folder.createFile(mGoogleApiClient, metadataChangeSet, driveContents).setResultCallback(fileCallback1);
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations функции работы с BitMap там реализованы с помощью NDK, что снимает ограничение на используемую память.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это известная проблема возникающая при декодировании битмапа из файла. Проблемная строка `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`

Чтобы ее решить, на старых версиях Android'а (до KitKat), достаточно было указывать битмап выгружаемым на диск:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inPurgeable=true;
```

Для новых версий - этот фокус уже не работает и приходится извращаться по другому, например:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565; //отводит на пиксель 2 байта, вместо 4-х по умолчанию
bmOptions.inDither = true;
```

В итоге размер битмапа сокращается в 2 раза.

**Update**

Судя по логам у вас слишком большой размер битмапа (>60 мегов) - это очень много, явно больше разрешения девайса. Соответственно при декодировании я бы его смасштабировал, например так:

```
bmOptions.inSampleSize=4; //уменьшит размеры в 4 раза
```

то есть занимаемая память уменьшится в 16 раз, до 16 мегов. Если не поможет, то надо увеличивать до 5 или 6.

Почитайте [эту статейку](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Если не поможет - резать на меньшие куски, отдавать на свой сервер, там склеивать и оттуда уже в GD.

Comment: к сожалению не помогло, а закидываю я в googleDrive, не получится склеивать их

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: Спасибо но он тоже не подходит, он просто обрезает фотографии, а мне нужно загружать не обрезанное и полное, я писал это в вопросе

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать

```
decodeStream(is, outPadding, opts)

BitmapFactory.Options opts=new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inDither=false;                    
opts.inPurgeable=true;                   
opts.inInputShareable=true;              
opts.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
```

Comment: Дело не в загрузке изображения а в его обработке перед загрузкой, когда я обрабатываю не хватает памяти вываливает по ошибке OutOfMemoryError

Comment: @YeldosTanikin понял. Извиняюсь. Сейчас подумаю.

Comment: @YeldosTanikin обновил ответ!

Comment: что за метод decodeStream и что ему мне передавать?

Comment: @YeldosTanikin как описал человек выше:
Это известная проблема возникающая при декодировании битмапа из файла. Проблемная строка BitmapFactory.decodeFile()